# Progressive data loading and processing in Spark

Tags: dataframe, performance, pyspark, hive, spark-streaming

Due to processing performance issues in my hadoop cluster, I am wondering if there is a way to load and process data from big hive table by small batches, so that available culster memory remains sufficient and multiple users can work simultanuously. For example, instead of loading a Spark dataframe of 100 million rows whom the processing time may be very long and all available memory consumed, load and process 100 dataframes one after one, each having only 1 million rows. I was thinking about streaming in Spark but I am not sure if it is the simplest and more efficient solution.

Thank you in advance.

When I load a very big dataframe, its processing consumes big resources and prevents colleagues from executing their jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is:

- Make sure the cluster is using the [FAIR](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) schedule mode, so jobs can share the cluster resources together and not in `FIFO` order.
- Limit the resources your job is consuming by controlling the number of executor's cores, memory and number of instances, so you can leave a room for other jobs to run in parallel. You can use these configurations

  - `spark.conf.set("spark.executor.cores", MAX_CORES)`
  - `spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", MAX_MEMORY)`
  - If `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is enabled

    - `spark.conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", MAX_EXECUTORS)`
  - If `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is disabled

    - `spark.conf.set("spark.executor.instances", MAX_EXECUTORS)`
- You could also limit each partition size so it can fit in the smaller executor size using the `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` configuration